# Regex for IP validation while taking into account broadcast and network addresses

Tags: python, regex

I've found a regex to validate IP addresses, but the one I found didn't take into account stuff like broadcast addresses or network addresses and also didn't account for less than 4 numbers. So I've managed to make this one myself:

`/^((2[0-5]{2}|1\d{2}|(1|\d[2-9]))\.{1})((2[0-5]{2}|1\d{2}|\d{1,2})\.{1}){2}(2[0-5]{2}|1\d{2}|(\d{2}|[2-9]))$/g`

Here's it's IP range:

1.0.0.2 to 255.255.255.254

It's my first custom regex, so I'm pretty sure it can be shorten, and I don't care if it becomes unreadable, I just want it to work and be short.

Is there some regex magic to shorten it ?

Comment: Try `ipaddress.IPv4Address(your_ip_address)`. Will raise an expection if invalid.

Comment: Can you clarify what what you consider valid or not? Well-formed and within the `1.0.0.2-255.255.255.254` range?

Does it have to be done using a regex?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)